# Does any integral of a function has an inner product form?

Tags: functional-analysis

It is well-known that the inner product defined on a vector space $V$, is a map:

$\langle f, g\rangle : = \int f(x)g(x) dx$, for all $f,g \in V$.

My question is if any integral has an inner product also ?

if yes, then what is the inner product form of

$\int f(x) dx$ for $f\in V$ ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you looking for something like $\int f(x)\,dx = \int f(x) 1\,dx = \langle f, 1\rangle$, where $1$ is the constant function with value $1$?

Comment: @Wauzl, I thought like this, but if $F \in C^1$ and $\partial F = f$, according to the argument, $F = \langle f, 1\rangle$ ? it is a bit strange

Comment: An inner product always has real or complex values, not functions. The integral has to be definite.

Comment: @Wauzl, thanks. You refreshed my mind !